# Is there any closed form for the following expectation?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, binomial-distribution

Suppose $X \sim Binomial(N,p)$. Is there any closed-form expression for the following expectation, $E[\frac{N-X}{(X+1)^2}]$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form though there may be a recurrence.  For $p=\frac12$ you seem to get $\frac12,\frac58, \frac{29}{48},\frac{103}{192}, \ldots$ which are $\frac{N}{2^N}$ times $1,\frac54, \frac{29}{18},\frac{103}{48}, \ldots$ and that represents the binomial transform of $1/(N + 1)^2$.

Comment: You probably want the steps involved but if you're willing to take what *Mathematica* gives, the expectation is $\frac{(n+1)^2 p (1-p)^n \, _3F_2\left(1,1,-n;2,2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)+(1-p)^{n+1}-1}{(n+1) p}$. where $_3F_2$ is the generalized hypergeometric funciton.